# How to use merge in postgresql for delta load

Tags: merge, postgresql-9.2

I would like to use merge in postgresql for delta load (insert, update and delete). 
There is one source and one target table.
What is the query for that? 
I am using PostgreSQL 9.2. 
Is merge statement fast on big (million rows) tables ?

Comment: There is no `merge` statement in Postgres (neither in the somewhat outdated version 9.2, nor in the current one). If you upgrade to 9.5 or later, you could make use of `insert .. on conflict`

Comment: Is it the upsert statement in 9.5? Does it also deletes the deleted rows in source?

Comment: Yes it's in 9.5 and no it does not delete anything.